# Datadog APM through api request

Tags: api, service, datadog, apm

I am using Datadog to monitor my kubernetes applicaitons.
I would like to use the Datadog api to fetch all services under the [section APM](https://app.datadoghq.com/apm/services) but I can't figure out which endpoints to use.

is that even possible?

I just expect to do an api request that returns me all services visible under APM -> services in the Datadog website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GET` method of the `service definitions` endpoint. [Here are the docs.](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/service-definition/#get-all-service-definitions) The docs include a number of examples, as well as other endpoints including retrieving an individual service by name.

```bash
curl -X GET "https://api.datadoghq.com/api/v2/services/definitions" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "DD-API-KEY: ${DD_API_KEY}" \
-H "DD-APPLICATION-KEY: ${DD_APP_KEY}"
```

Comment: he asked how to list services under apm, not to list the created definitions of the services  under apm, probably needs the list to create the definitions himself